# Count TD number of different tables with same classes

Tags: jquery

Let's say we have two tables with same classes, the only difference is the number of columns.

```
<table class="lives prono_live">
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table class="lives prono_live">
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>           
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want a jQuery function which gaves me each table's TD number in one loop.

I created this code:

```
$( '.lives.prono_live' ).each(function( index ) {
    alert($('.lives.prono_live td').length);
});
```

This code is not good, just partly.

What this code does:

- Shows two alert box with the value 9 and 9

What I want to have:

- Shows two alert box with the value 4 and 5

Anyone knows how to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

cause your code is counting all `tds` since you have class selector inside loop `$('.lives.prono_live td')`... use `$(this)` reference and it should work..

try this

```
$( '.lives.prono_live' ).each(function( index ) {
  alert($(this).find('td').length); 
});
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/gzsAG/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `this`, otherwise you get both with the class selector.

```
$( '.lives.prono_live' ).each(function( index ) {
    alert($(this).find('td').length);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
$(".lives.prono_live").each(function() {
    alert($("td", this).length);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

While in the $.each() loop, you need to target the "current" element with $(this).

```
$( '.lives.prono_live' ).each( function( index ) {
    alert( $( this ).find( 'td' ).length );
});
```