# DataTables: Using AJAX, count how many rows in total have a specific value in a cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

My code is:

```
var table1 = $('#view-table').DataTable( {
        fixedHeader: true,
        "search": {
            "smart": false
        },

        "columnDefs": [
            {
                "targets": [ 0,16 ],
                "visible": false,
                "bSearchable": true
            },
            { 
                "orderable": false, 
                "targets": [ 1,15 ] 
            }
        ],

        "createdRow": function( row, data, dataIndex ) {

            if ( data[16] == "yes" ) {   
                $(row).addClass('warning');
            }
            if ( data[0] == "yes" ) {   
                $(row).removeClass('warning');
                $(row).addClass('success');
            }
        },
        "ajax": '/getViewData',
        "pageLength": 25
    });
```

I have looked at [jQuery How to count the no of rows in table by distinct column value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21239557/jquery-how-to-count-the-no-of-rows-in-table-by-distinct-column-value) but it only brings back what's on the screen at the time.

What I need is to see how many rows have the value of `'yes'` in the 16th column for **all** the data that is brought back. Not just the data is on the screen. Everything.

All the examples I've tried, as the one above, only work where it's not AJAX based

Comment: Uhm, I believe you just want `var count = 0;` on top of your callback and then when it's `yes`, just `count += 1;`. Is that it?

Comment: I could only get that to work when it was static, not ajax and not for ever row in the data returned i.e. just for data on the screen at the time

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem a few weeks ago, I'm not sure if this is the best solution but it did the work then:

```
var count = table1.rows(function(idx, data, node) {
  return data[16] == 'yes'
}).count();
```

**EDIT:** If you want that count after the ajax ends, you can user `initComplete`

```
initComplete: function(row, data, index) {
   var count = table1.rows(function(idx, data, node) {
      return data[16] == 'yes'
   }).count();
   console.log('count: ', count);
}, // initComplete()
```

**EDIT 2**: add [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dr4d6Ljc/5/)

Comment: This doesn't work with ajax data - and it only works on stuff I see on the screen, unless I shouldn't be using initComplete?

Comment: I was showing the count on an user action, but yes, you can use it on initComplete callback. Check the edit.

Comment: Still only counts on what's visible rather than everything else

Comment: I add a jsfiddle, It doesn't check the 'yes' just some numbers, but you'll get the idea. Otherwise, paste your full implementation.

Answer (score -1):

You should probably use ajax callback.
Instead of this `"ajax": '/getViewData'` do this:

```js
"ajax": {
  "type": "GET",
  "url": "/getViewData",
  "dataSrc": function(json){
    //Count your rows here
    return json.data;
  }  
}
```